# How to pass the NSString from One UIViewController to Another UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS - Passing variable to view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272864/ios-passing-variable-to-view-controller)

I have two Viewcontrollers (ViewController1 and ViewController2) , And i want to pass a String value along with a IBAction from ViewController1 to ViewController2. I am trying to read the NSString (*check) value in ViewController2's ViewDidLoad method, but it's returning a null value.

Help me out and Thanks in advance.

```
// ViewController1

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController {

        IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
        IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
        NSString *check;
    }
#import "ViewController.h"

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    check = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if (btn1.tag == 0) {
        check = @"foo";
        NSLog(@"%@",check);    
    }
    if (btn2.tag == 1) {
        check = @"bar";
        NSLog(@"%@",check);
    }
}
```

in my second view controller ,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController1;

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController {

    ViewController1 *viewCon;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) ViewController *viewCon;

//.m

#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"

@synthesize viewCon,

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ViewController *myVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"  Label  %@",myVC.check);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998623/passing-nsstring-from-one-class-to-the-other  , see duplicate of this....  :D :D: D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

   //check = [[NSString alloc] init]; -- NO Need

    if (btn1.tag == 0) {
        check = @"foo";
        NSLog(@"%@",check);    
    }
    if (btn2.tag == 1) {
        check = @"bar";
        NSLog(@"%@",check);
    }

  ViewController2 *obj = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2"];
  [obj setCheck:check];
  //push to ViewController2
  [obj release];
```

}

In your second view controller,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController {

        NSString *check;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *check;


//.m

#import "ViewController2.h"

@synthesize check;


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"  Label  %@",check);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass data from ViewController1 to ViewController2 using instance ofViewController2 followed by dot operator:

Create a property of NSString *strCheck in ViewController2 as u want to pass data to ViewController2.

Now in button's click event of ViewController1

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
{

 .......
 .......

 ViewController2 *objViewController2 = [ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
 objViewController2.strCheck = check; //ViewController1's value to ViewController2

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this link -

 [iOS - Passing variable to view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272864/ios-passing-variable-to-view-controller/11274661#11274661) . 

I have already given answer for same thing.

You need to set variable's `@property` and `@synthesized`. For more check the link.