# Press a Button and open a URL in another ViewController

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsurl, viewcontroller

I am trying to learn Xcode by making a simple app. 
But I been looking on the net for hours (days) and I cant figure it out how I make a button that open a UIWebView in another ViewController :S

first let me show you some code that I have ready:

I have a few Buttons om my main Storyboard that each are title some country codes like UK, CA and DK.

When I press one of those Buttons I have an IBAction like this:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
// Google button pressed

NSURL* allURLS;

if([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"DK"]) {

    // Create URL obj

    allURLS = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.dk"];



}else if([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"US"])

{

    allURLS = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

}else if([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"CA"])

{

    allURLS = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.ca"];

}
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:allURLS];

[myWebView loadRequest:req];
```

}

How do I make this open UIWebview on my other Viewcontroller named myWebView?

please help a lost man :D

Comment: Do u want to push to another view controller? Is yes then declare a string variable in that view controller and pass this url to that variable. Then load the string url in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: @Suresh how do I do that?, I am a new n00b in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've firstViewController already designed and coded, now you've to create secondViewController with a `UIWebView` binded in `IB` it self, also it have a setter `NSString` variable like `strUrl` that you need to pass at the time of pushing or presenting secondViewController, and assign it to `UIWebView` in `viewDidLoad` of secondViewController. [See my answer about how to pass a `NSString`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12436857/1603234) Also `UIWebView` has its delegates method ([What's delegate & datasource methods? - Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html)) Which you can use to handle `URL` request.

These are the `delegate` of `UIWebView`, if you'll going to use it, you need to give `UIWebView` delegate to `self`.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: Can you give me some complete examples ?

Comment: Check *Suresh* answer, he's given complete example! :)

Answer (score 0):

firstViewController.m

```
   - (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSURL* allURLS;
    //get your URL
    secondViewControlelr *secondView=[[secondViewControlelr alloc]init];
    second.urlToLoad=allURLS;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    }
```

secondViewControlelr.h
//declare url and set property

```
NSURL *urlToLoad;
```

secondViewControlelr.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
         myWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
         [self.view addSubview:myWebView];
          NSURLRequest *urlReq=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.urlToLoad cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10];
    [myWebView loadRequest:urlReq];

}
```

Comment: okay I tryed that, and edit for my code, but I get error(s) in the second.urltoload=allURLS; the error is "Use of undeclared identifier 'second'

Comment: okay that got fixed. But I don't understand what to type in my secondviewcontroller.h file?