# Running data from the first ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Here is my question:

I have two view controllers (identified as ViewController1 and ViewController2)

ViewController2 has a label that is populated with text in a string format from ViewController1

I would like to manipulate that text from ViewController2.

I this possible?

Basically, I have a label that posts random information from the string and I would like to refresh this string that posts on label.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If ViewController1 pushes or present ViewController2:

To send a message from VC1 to VC2, just create a public method on VC2 and call it from VC1.

To send a message from VC2 to CV1, create a delegate on VC2 and implement it on VC1.

Answer (score 0):

Make a property in VC2 and put the string in the VC2.property at the time of pushing the VC2 from VC1.

Read about property and message passing

Comment: I've had no problem pushing VC2 from VC1. The issue is reloading that string in order to view a new information on the label? Am I missing something?

Comment: @coolMed Never said you have problem in pushing view. Just told you to make  a property in VC2 which you can access in VC1. Consider this tutorial http://devinsheaven.com/cocoa-tutorial-passing-messages-between-objects-notifications-delegates-and-target-action/

Answer (score 0):

Refer my answer to a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872762/1051215) (global variable in appDelegate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208511/1051215) (properties)

Or you can use singleton

Comment: Singleton ! are you serious ?

Comment: @Dushyant Singh Yes, it is better to use singletons other than having lot of global variables in AppDelegate. Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: he asked for sending a NSString from VC1 to VC2 , cant it done by simple use of property ? So you make Global variables and singleton for just message passing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt two option for it.

1) You can take a string property in VC2 and set it in VC1 when pushing VC2 OR

2) You can set that string in preferences in VC1 and use it from preferences in VC2